# Extracting values from a JSON object

Tags: json

I am trying to extract the values from a JSON object. Currently I am able to check that the item is in the object with

```
jsonObj.responseText.search('item');
```

I have tried using the following:

```
obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
alert(obj.item);
```

To see if I can extract the value of "item" but it does not work, I don't get an alert dialog at all.

Can anyone give me some ideas about what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is "item"? A value or another JSON object/JSON array?

Comment: @DavidCAdams "item" is any given key in the JSON object.

Comment: OK. jsonObj.getString("item"), or jsonObj.getInt("item"), etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
java.util.Iterator keyIterator = jsonObj.keys();

String key; 
while(keyIterator.hasNext()){
    key = (String)keyIterator.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + key + "    Value: " + jsonObject.get(key));
}
```

This will print out all your JSON object's key/values. You can just use JSONObject getters to get the values you want once you know the keys. i.e.  String value = jsonObj.getString("some_key")

Comment: Ended up using your comment answer. Thanks DavidCAdams